# Creating my own Actitivities and XML-based layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game in Android with a game engine that has custom layouts to show data from user. Don't think why it's done in this way. It's only an example.

Now, I want to migrate my game to Unity.

My game is a collaborative game that needs to show users connected to the game. The game uses a REST service to communicate with others players. Also, the game is splits in challenge, and I need a list to show them.

Can I do all of this with Unity? May I merge my actual Android project with a Unity project?